# Preview my site as guest user

Tags: 2013, permissions

I'm completely new to SP and I don't understand how I preview my website as an external user?

How can I see what users that aren't admins/got any permissions see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is Anonymous Access, you need to turn on Anonymous access for the site and once you check-in and publish the pages.. You can open those pages as Anonymous access (without any user logged in)

Please have a look at:

[How to Enable Anonymous Access on SharePoint 2013 site](https://support.cloudshare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200701115-How-to-Enable-Anonymous-Access-to-a-SharePoint-2013-site)